# how can I turn this list comprehension into for loops

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I was looking at itertools.product, and in the explanation is a function meant to explain how the function kinda works. It looks like all the magic happens here, in a loop through the lists: result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in list]. So I decided to try to create a couple loops so I can more easily follow exactly what is going on. I modified the example function to this:

```
lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

result = [[]]
for l in lists:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in l]

print result
```

And the result is what I was expecting. However when I tried to break it down into for loops, I ended up getting tripped up with the looping through result while modifying it (which I read you shouldn't do). My attempt:

```
lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

result = [[]]
for l in lists:
    for i in result:
        for y in l:
            result.append([i+[y]])

print result
```

How would you recreate the list comprehension with loops in this case?

Comment: You're breaking out the lists backwards from the list comprehension. Also, you seem to be setting `result` a bunch of times (once for each `l` in `lists`) and then successively overwriting it.

Comment: The "equivalent" code for `itertools.product` isn't very intuitive or Pythonic, and it's not really equivalent to the C implementation, either (as explained in the docs). Maybe it would be worth [filing a docs bug](http://bugs.python.org/) suggesting something more like {Bhargav Rao's implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30792087/908494) instead (or just the direct equivalent of the C code, which is more verbose but not hard to follow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a temporary list that holds your intermediate lists. This is because the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) completely executes and then re-writes the value of `result`.

A small code can be demonstrated as follows

```
result = [[]]
for l in lists:
    tmp = []
    for x in result:
        for y in l:
            tmp.append(x+[y])
    result = tmp
```

This will print the same value as required.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel pretty silly now, but I was expecting that. I should read more into list comprehensions.

Comment: Hey brother, nah. There is nothing silly bout this. We all are learners at some point of time :)